# How to rescue ruby callbacks?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

Is there a simple way to wrap ruby/rails with begin rescue blocks?

We're implementing the search functionality in our webapp, using ElasticSearch + Tire. Tire uses callbacks on models that we want to index on the ES server. Sometimes these callbacks fail for some reason.

I want to be able to rescue these errors - Is there a simple way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Without you providing more detail, what about something like this

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

    after_save :my_callback

    def my_callback
        begin
          # do the thing you want
        rescue
          # callback failed - raise error or whetever
        end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check out http://mrchrisadams.tumblr.com/post/333036266/catching-errors-in-rails-with-rescue-from, which discusses the `rescue_from` capability and how to use it application wide.